# Cordova compile android - command.com

Tags: cordova, command

I'm trying to build my .apk but I get this error.

I've searched and only solution was to rename the cmd.exe, but when I run the command.com I get same error.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5K86u.png

Answer (score 1):

From [Cordova's documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html):

To build apk:

```
cordova build
```

To run in emulator:

```
cordova emulate android
```

To run on your device:

```
cordova run android
```

Note that you need to add Android to your **PATH**, you'll find the details here: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide